# Read a particular name value pair from JSON with multiple objects using Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

```
{
 "name":"xyz",
 "result":"success"
}
```

I need to compare the result and if it is success replace with a new `Activity`. I am using retrofit call back methods. How to i read only a particular name pair and how to proceed if i had a multiple objects say `JSON Array`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for read a particular name value pair from JSON.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json_string);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
    String result = jsonobject.getString("result");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello friends you can do it with this way for jsonobject data .
x="your data".......... in this case this is best

JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(x);

```
    String name=jobj.getString("name");
    String result=jobj.getString("result");
```

if you want to know some more about json object or JsonArray this is simple use this web site for know object and Array of Json

"[Look at here this is Link](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)...