# Read a particular object from JSON file with multiple objects using RETROFIT in android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

[ {
     "name:"ABC",
     "ID":"123"
    },
    {
     "name:"xyz",
     "ID":"456"
    }
]
I want to read a `JSON` object with name whose value is **ABC** 
how to write a method with `HTTP` annotations and query parameters in  interface.

Comment: this is invalid json you can see this at this link also http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/             to view your json

Comment: look at this link here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411089/read-a-particular-name-value-pair-from-json-with-multiple-objects-using-retrofit/32411206#32411206

Comment: [{"name":"ABC","ID":123},
{"name":"xyz","ID":456}] here is the JSON data.. please help

Answer (score 0):

this is the right answer for your jsonarray for this response :-

[{"name":"ABC","ID":123}, {"name":"xyz","ID":456}]

```
 String[] x=[{"name":"ABC","ID":123}, {"name":"xyz","ID":456}]

or x= your response data

 try {
        JSONArray jarr=new JSONArray(x);
        for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jobj=jarr.getJSONObject(i);

            String name=jobj.getString("name");
            String ID=jobj.getString("ID");
            System.out.println("name=="+name+"id==="+ID);

        }   

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[see this link for geting json data](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)